# Create Json from a mysql Result Set Resembling a Tree

Tags: php, mysql, json, algorithm, tree

The problem is to get the following result set:

```
       'org1', 'unit1', 'proj1'
       'org1', 'unit1', 'proj2'
       'org1', 'unit2', 'proj1'
       'org1', 'unit2', 'proj2'           
       'org2', 'unit1', 'proj1'
       'org2', 'unit1', 'proj2'
```

to the following in php:

```
[{"units": [{"name": "unit1", "projects": ["project1", "project2"]}, {"name": "unit2", "projects": ["project1", "project2"]}], "name": "org1"}, {"units": [{"name": "unit1", "projects": ["project1", "project2"]}], "name": "org2"}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, my suggestion is study a tutorial on dealing with json in php

Comment: who knows what are these `'org1', 'unit1', 'proj1'`

Comment: convert json into above mention format???? this is the question?

Comment: @devpro, yeah, can you solve?

Comment: @sisanared, it is not a json_encode question, but adopting the right data structure. Wanted to know whether there's any built in way to transform a inline tree structure to an object in php without having to write the tree logic myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($array as $row){
  $final_array[$row[0]][$row[1]][] = $row[2];
}
```

Now this will **"convert the SQL result array into a multidimentional array/tree"** but not like what you want yet.
So we shall have to process the array again..

```
$final_array_2 = array(); // Lets go deep
foreach ($final_array as $name => $units) {
    $quarterfinal_array = array(); // Not deep enough
    $semi_final_array = array();
    foreach ($units as $proj_name => $projects) {
        $nano_final_array = array(); // Lets dig deeper ;)
        $nano_final_array['name'] = $proj_name;
        $nano_final_array['projects'] = $projects;
        $semi_final_array[] = $nano_final_array;
    }
    $quarterfinal_array['units'] = $semi_final_array;
    $quarterfinal_array['name'] = $name;

    $final_array_2[] = $quarterfinal_array;
}



echo json_encode($final_array_2);
```

PS: Sorry my choice of variable names are not the most ideal, but they get the work done ;) This is a P.O.C, You can always improve on it.

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/KydftETM)**

Comment: @c00der Can you please select my answer as "the answer".